# Using caffe weights in 8 bit resolution system

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network

Im new with caffe, I have trained lenet network and I have extracted the weights of convolution layers. I obtained the next values from a row of 7x7 convolution filter:

```
[[ 0.06115171 -0.12328118 -0.05160818 -0.10334936 -0.01025871 -0.0503762
   -0.07576288]]
```

I would like to know if I have to use these weights with 8 bit resolution, should I multiply these values by 255?

Answer (score 1):

These values are floating point (probably 32 bits per number) what values do you have in your system that are represented by 8 bits? Are they `uint8`? `int8`? fixed point?
If you want to scale your values, you usually scale (by x255) the inputs rather than the weights.

Comment: the number are represented in int8 , how can I represent those values in that format?Because all weights would be 0 no?

Comment: @user3780043 it's not trivial to quantize floating point (32bits) numbers into 8 bits. You need to scale and probably shift the numbers. There is a nice explanation on quantization in the context of deep learning in [Tensorflow web page](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization). I think it can be a good starting point.